# Cannot publish pom for project ':' it does not contain the Maven plugin install task and task ':artifactoryPublish' doesn't specify a custom pom path

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory

I am trying to publish/deploy jar (in build/lib) file created by my gradle project to artifactory. To make things simple I installed a local artifactory-oss installation without docker. When I execute the command gradlew build artifactoryDeploy then output shows following

> Cannot publish pom for project ':' since it does not contain the Maven
> plugin install task and task ':artifactoryPublish' does not specify a
> custom pom path.
>
> ```
> > Task :artifactoryDeploy
> Deploying build info...
> Build-info successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://100.100.11.11:8081/artifactory/webapp/builds/mygradle/1846079453857
> ```

I tried following [jfrog documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin#:%7E:text=The%20Gradle%20Artifactory%20Plugin%20allows,supported%20Gradle%20version%20is%204.10.) and [other resources](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-deploying-and-resolving-different-artifact-types-through-a-gradle-job/) but still it is just pushing the build info.

My gradle.build looks like following

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://100.100.11.11:8081/artifactory/gradle-release-local'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
    }
}

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}

task createPom {
doLast{
pom { 
        project { 
            groupId 'edc'
            artifactId 'mygradle'
            version '1.0.0'
        }
    }.writeTo("pom.xml")
} 
    
}

allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
  group = 'org.jfrog.example.gradle'
  version = "4.21.0"
  status = "release"
}

configurations {
  published
}

def f1 = file("to_deploy.txt")
def f2 = file("build/libs/mygradle-1.0.0-sources.jar")

artifacts {
    published file: f1, name: f1.getName(), type: 'txt'
    published file: f2, name: f2.getName(), type: 'jar'
}

artifactoryPublish {
      skip = false //Skip build info analysis and publishing (false by default)
      contextUrl = 'http://100.100.11.11:8081/artifactory'
      publications ('ALL_PUBLICATIONS')
  
      clientConfig.publisher.repoKey = 'gradle-release-local'
      clientConfig.publisher.username = "${artifactory_user}"
      clientConfig.publisher.password = "${artifactory_password}"
  }

artifactory {
  contextUrl = 'http://100.100.11.11:8081/artifactory'
  publish {
    repository {
      repoKey = 'gradle-release-local'
      username = "${artifactory_user}"
      password = "${artifactory_password}"
      maven = true
    }
    defaults {
      publications('ALL_PUBLICATIONS')
      publishConfigs('published')     
      publishBuildInfo = true
      publishArtifacts = true
      publishPom = true
      publishIvy = true
    }
  }
  resolve {
    repository {
      repoKey = 'maven-remote'
      username = "admin"
      password = "password"
    }
  }
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar){
    from file("build/libs/mygradle-1.0.0-sources.jar")
 }

 publishing {
      publications {
           pluginJar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "${group}"
            artifactId 'mygradle'                         // this is the package suffix the jar will go into in artifactory
            version "${version}"
            artifact sourceJar
            from components.java
        }
      }
  }
```

I know there might be somethings extra in this build.gradle file but I added those to just try them out. Is it possible to publish/deploy a gradle project to artifactory without setting up jenkins? If yes then where my build.gradle is lacking?

I know that it is possible with maven build projects. As I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your query, Yes you can make use of [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) as an alternate or another way to integrate Gradle client to the Artifactory application. This will help to resolve dependencies and deploy build artifacts from and to Artifactory and also collects the build-info which will be stored in Artifactory. For more details on this, you may refer to our CLI Wiki page [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningGradleBuilds).

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was adding the `maven` plugin (I previously only had the `maven-publish` plugin):

```
plugins {
  id 'maven'
  id 'maven-publish'
  id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' version '4.29.0'
}
```